# React Native stops executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code

```
  <DocumentPicker
      onDone={(res: DocumentPickerResponse[]) => {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty('isCancel')) {
        } else {
          handleDocumentPicker(res);
          handleAttachmentResizing();
        }
        toggleDocumentPicker();
      }}
```

DocumentPicker allows the user to choose a video from their gallery, once they choose the video `handleDocumentPicker` gets the results array and sets my `attachments` array state.
`handleAttachmentResizing` is then called to resize all the video attachments in my `attachments` state.

This is how the `handleAttachmentResizing` looks like

```
 const handleAttachmentResizing = async () => {
console.log('handleAttachmentResizing called');
try {
  console.log('handleAttachmentResizing called try');
  lodash.forEach(newAttachments, async (item, idx) => {
    console.log('handleAttachmentResizing called try lodash');
    console.log('handleAttachmentResizing loop ', idx);
    if (!item.isCompressed && !item.isCompressing && isVideo(item.type)) {
      const resizedVideo = await resizeVideo(item, idx);
      if (resizedVideo) {
        const uri = await moveFile(resizedVideo);
        const update: Attachment = {
          ...item,
          isCompressed: true,
          isCompressing: false,
          uri,
        };
        updateAttachment(item.uri, update);
      }
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.error('handleAttachmentResizing ', err);
}
console.log('handleAttachmentResizing called');
```

};

And `resizeVideo` looks like this

```
  const resizeVideo = async (attachment: Attachment, idx: number) => {
console.log('resizeVideo called');
try {
  return await Video.compress(
    attachment.uri,
    {
      compressionMethod: 'auto',
      getCancellationId: (cancellationId) =>
        setVideoCancellationToken(cancellationId),
    },
    (progress) => {
      if(mounted.current){
      const updated: Attachment = {
        ...attachment,
        progress,
        isCompressing: true,
      };
      updateAttachment(attachment.uri, updated);
    }else {
      //Video.cancelCompression()
      handleRemoveAttachment(attachment, idx);
    }
    },
  );
} catch (err) {
  console.error('resizeVideo ', err);
  handleRemoveAttachment(attachment, idx);
}
};
```

I'm not sure why but `handleAttachmentResizing` only prints `handleAttachmentResizing called try` and ends there, if I choose another file in my gallery, it mysteriously continues executing.